# Saving Files on EMR EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I'm having diskspace issues when downloading files from S3 to my EMR nodes. I'm using c3.4xlarge nodes, which are supposed to have 160GB of space, yet when using addFile with in PySpark to send the files (8 450MB files), I get  `No space left on device` errors.

Any idea why this is happening?

I notice a similar issue when downloading the files via the AWS CLI on the master node.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are placing the files on the correct partition that has all that space? I believe you need to copy them to the `/mnt` directory. Running `df -H` on one of the servers will show you where your space is.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, though I had to sudo to write to that directory.

Comment: Given that I need these files in the /mnt folder in each slave, is it possible to add a step to copy files from S3 to the same file path on each slave?